# Cannot open table mysql/innodb_index_stats

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows, linux, mysql-5.6

After a fresh install of XAMPP and import from my linux live db that is working to the windows Dev-stage, I started encountering problems with `INSERT`. Everything else seems to work well.

The errors I get in the `mysql_error.log` are:

```
2013-08-15 12:44:49 16c0 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2013-08-15 12:44:49 16c0 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "sizaradb"."pages" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
2013-08-15 12:44:59 16c0 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2013-08-15 12:44:59 16c0 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "sizaradb"."translations" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
```

I cannot open table `mysql/innodb_index_stats` from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists

I tried to fix it by googling the errors and trying to see fixes of other people, but it is still not working. I have been working on this for 2 days now.

Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## PROBLEM

In MySQL 5.6, `ibdata1` includes 5 InnoDB in the `mysql` schema.

```
mysql> select table_name from information_schema.tables
    -> where table_schema='mysql' and engine='InnoDB';
+----------------------+
| table_name           |
+----------------------+
| innodb_index_stats   |
| innodb_table_stats   |
| slave_master_info    |
| slave_relay_log_info |
| slave_worker_info    |
+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

In MySQL versions before 5.6, if you shutdown mysql, delete `ibdata1`, and start mysql back up, `ibdata1` gets recreated. *If you do this with MySQL 5.6, these 5 tables are not recreated*. Even if your deleted `ibdata1`, the following 10 files are still in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`:

- `innodb_index_stats.frm`
- `innodb_index_stats.ibd`
- `innodb_table_stats.frm`
- `innodb_table_stats.ibd`
- `slave_master_info.frm`
- `slave_master_info.ibd`
- `slave_relay_log_info.frm`
- `slave_relay_log_info.ibd`
- `slave_worker_info.frm`
- `slave_worker_info.ibd`

I learned this early on. With a newly created or damaged `ibdata1`, there are no corresponding data dictionary entries for those 5 tables.

In your particular case, I suspect you copied `ibdata1` from a Linux server to the Windows server. MySQL/Windows would be expecting the data dictionary to have the DOS Filename Format. Moving that `ibdata1` to Windows, MySQL/Windows cannot relate to the Linux filename and path for pointing to the `.frm` and `.ibd` files.

## SOLUTION

**STEP 01** : Install MySQL on another DB Server

**STEP 02** : mysqldump only those 5 tables

```
TABLELIST="innodb_index_stats"
TABLELIST="${TABLELIST} innodb_table_stats"
TABLELIST="${TABLELIST} slave_master_info"
TABLELIST="${TABLELIST} slave_relay_log_info"
TABLELIST="${TABLELIST} slave_worker_info"
mysqldump -uroot -p mysql ${TABLELIST} > mysql_innodb_tables.sql
```

**STEP 03** : Copy `mysql_innodb_tables.sql` to the DB Server with bad tables.

**STEP 04** : Execute `mysql_innodb_tables.sql`

**STEP 05** : Run `FLUSH TABLES;` (Optional)

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: too much moves, just drop files, restart mysql and create tables as suggested in other answers!

Comment: @Tertium you are right. I wrote a better way four(4) months later : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys/54624#54624

Answer (score 15):

this bug is reported in MySQL Forums ([67179](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67179)) and the solution is mentioned [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=19725&bug_id=67179). please note that you should do clean-up, before creating tables

```
/* 
  temporary fix for problem with windows installer for MySQL 5.6.10 on Windows 7 machines.
  I did the procedure on a clean installed MySql, and it worked for me, at least it stopped
  lines of innodb errors in the log and the use of transient innodb tables. So, do it at
  your own risk..

  1. drop these tables from mysql:
     innodb_index_stats
     innodb_table_stats
     slave_master_info
     slave_relay_log_info
     slave_worker_info

  2. delete all .frm & .ibd of the tables above.

  3. run this file to recreate the tables above (source five-tables.sql).

  4. restart mysqld.

  Cheers, 
  CNL
*/

CREATE TABLE `innodb_index_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `index_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stat_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `stat_value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sample_size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stat_description` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`,`index_name`,`stat_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;

CREATE TABLE `innodb_table_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `n_rows` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clustered_index_size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sum_of_other_index_sizes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;

CREATE TABLE `slave_master_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log currently being read from the master.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last read event.',
  `Host` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The host name of the master.',
  `User_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The user name used to connect to the master.',
  `User_password` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The password used to connect to the master.',
  `Port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The network port used to connect to the master.',
  `Connect_retry` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The period (in seconds) that the slave will wait before trying to reconnect to the master.',
  `Enabled_ssl` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether the server supports SSL connections.',
  `Ssl_ca` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The file used for the Certificate Authority (CA) certificate.',
  `Ssl_capath` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The path to the Certificate Authority (CA) certificates.',
  `Ssl_cert` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the SSL certificate file.',
  `Ssl_cipher` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the cipher in use for the SSL connection.',
  `Ssl_key` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the SSL key file.',
  `Ssl_verify_server_cert` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Whether to verify the server certificate.',
  `Heartbeat` float NOT NULL,
  `Bind` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'Displays which interface is employed when connecting to the MySQL server',
  `Ignored_server_ids` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The number of server IDs to be ignored, followed by the actual server IDs',
  `Uuid` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The master server uuid.',
  `Retry_count` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of reconnect attempts, to the master, before giving up.',
  `Ssl_crl` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The file used for the Certificate Revocation List (CRL)',
  `Ssl_crlpath` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The path used for Certificate Revocation List (CRL) files',
  `Enabled_auto_position` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether GTIDs will be used to retrieve events from the master.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Port`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Master Information';

CREATE TABLE `slave_relay_log_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file or rows in the table. Used to version table definitions.',
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the current relay log file.',
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The relay log position of the last executed event.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log file from which the events in the relay log file were read.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last executed event.',
  `Sql_delay` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The number of seconds that the slave must lag behind the master.',
  `Number_of_workers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Internal Id that uniquely identifies this record.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Relay Log Information';

CREATE TABLE `slave_worker_info` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_seqno` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_group_size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_group_bitmap` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Worker Information';
```

Comment: Just a small note. On Linux make sure to restart mysql after deleting .frm and .ibd files. then creating the new tables works like a charm.

Comment: Good work bro !

Answer (score 3):

After an upgrade you need to run "mysql_upgrade -u root" and this will handle all the system table updates.

Comment: There was no upgrade mentioned - do you mean they need to do it first?

Comment: This solved the issue for me even though I had never done any upgrades.

Comment: we may need move or remove old  innodb_ and gtid_slave_pos files before do mysql_upgrade      

cd /var/lib/mysql; mv innodb_* gtid_slave_pos.* ~

Answer (score 3):

for mariadb10:

```
CREATE TABLE `gtid_slave_pos` (
  `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seq_no` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`,`sub_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Replication slave GTID state';

CREATE TABLE `innodb_index_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `index_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stat_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `stat_value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sample_size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stat_description` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`,`index_name`,`stat_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `innodb_table_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `n_rows` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clustered_index_size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sum_of_other_index_sizes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 2):

We hit the same problem on deploying 5.6  as part of our standards we always install from .rpm and relocate the data dir after the first set up . 5.5 and lower we would change our settings in the /etc/my.cnf stop mysql and then tar up the database directories in the default data dir and untar to our new one . As we change all our innodb settings we then got a nice new clean innoddb datafile.

So now before we stop our server we run the following on the mysql database

```
ALTER TABLE innodb_index_stats engine=MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE innodb_table_stats engine=MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE slave_master_info engine=MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE slave_relay_log_info engine=MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE slave_worker_info engine=MYISAM;
```

We then move all the data to the new location and restart mysql followed by another set of alters thus

```
ALTER TABLE innodb_index_stats engine=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE innodb_table_stats engine=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE slave_master_info engine=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE slave_relay_log_info engine=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE slave_worker_info engine=INNODB;
```

This seems to work fine for us and is quick to do

Comment: This is very good answer provided one remembers four(4) things: 1) the 5 InnoDB tables are inside MySQL 5.6 ibdata1 2), the `.ibd` exist in the `mysql` schema, 3) MySQL 5.5 has no upgrade path to MySQL 5.6 to make them, 4) your steps will only work with an ibdata1 generated by MySQL 5.6.