# ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this option

Tags: mysql, innodb, stored-procedures, myisam

I am new to MySQL administration, and this week a customer came to me with a problem. They created an application with Wamp in a Windows Server environment.

For some reason when listing the tables in the MySQL Workbench, an error pops up saying `could not be fetched`.

[image: MySQL Workbench]

And in the output window, the following error is thrown:

[image]

They also reported that a stored procedure has disappeared, and when trying to compile it again in MySQL, another error is generated:

```
ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this option
```

Some tables were using the MyISAM engine, so I changed it and now all are as INNODB, and the ROW FORMAT parameters are like Do not Use.

Other information that may be important, this base was developed in a version 5.1, and this base with problems is in version 5.7.14.

**UPDATE**:  I just tried to run mysqldump, to import on another server.
And this error was thrown:

```
d:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin>mysqldump.exe -u root --routines  --all-data
bases --force > dump20170912.sql
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'bejarti'': Table s
torage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this option (1031)
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'berbigier'': Table
 storage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this option (1031)
mysqldump: Got error: 1031: Table storage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this op
tion when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `proc`': Table storage engine for
 'proc' doesn't have this option (1031)
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'mysql'': Table sto
rage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this option (1031)
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'new_schema'': Tabl
e storage engine for 'proc' doesn't have this option (1031)
```

Comment: What versions of Workbench and of mysqldump?

Comment: Workbench 6.3.10 and mysqldump Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 5.6, five(5) InnoDB tables were introduced to the `mysql` schema. I mentioned and described those tables in my 4-year-old answer to the post [InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found after upgrade to mysql 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys/54624#54624)

For MySQL 5.7, it went to 19.

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.12    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select table_name from information_schema.tables
    -> where table_schema='mysql' and engine='InnoDB';
+---------------------------+
| table_name                |
+---------------------------+
| engine_cost               |
| gtid_executed             |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| innodb_index_stats        |
| innodb_table_stats        |
| plugin                    |
| server_cost               |
| servers                   |
| slave_master_info         |
| slave_relay_log_info      |
| slave_worker_info         |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
+---------------------------+
19 rows in set (0.53 sec)

mysql>
```

Please note the remaining `mysql` tables

```
mysql> select table_name,engine from information_schema.tables
    -> where table_schema='mysql' and engine <> 'InnoDB';
+------------------+--------+
| table_name       | engine |
+------------------+--------+
| columns_priv     | MyISAM |
| db               | MyISAM |
| event            | MyISAM |
| func             | MyISAM |
| general_log      | CSV    |
| ndb_binlog_index | MyISAM |
| proc             | MyISAM |
| procs_priv       | MyISAM |
| proxies_priv     | MyISAM |
| slow_log         | CSV    |
| tables_priv      | MyISAM |
| user             | MyISAM |
+------------------+--------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As shown, `mysql.proc` (where stored procedures and functions are stored) is supposed to remain as MyISAM. I have mentioned these table counts before (see the subheading "CAVEAT FOR MySQL 5.6/5.7 users" in my answer [Will hacking away ibdata1 destroy databases with only MyISAM tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141849/will-hacking-away-ibdata1-destroy-databases-with-only-myisam-tables/142072#142072))

## LESSON HERE

You should never convert any table in the `mysql` schema into any storage engine. Changing them only made matters worse. The solution to this problem may  have been as simple as executing `REPAIR TABLE mysql.proc;`.

Comment: As system tables were not converted deliberately and did not try to convert again.

Unfortunately I saw your response after we decided to restore the environment, otherwise we would have tried to repair the table.

This tip was very helpful, it will certainly help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that several system tables were corrupted, and due to time, it was necessary to reinstall MySQL.