# How do I stop MYSQL trying to load a missing InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Everytime I start MySQL, I receive the error:

`Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\deleteddatabase\deletedtable.ibd' OS error: 103`

I can't `DROP` the table, because it doesn't exist. There's no corresponding `.frm` file. I presume that somewhere in `ibdata1` there's a reference to this old InnoDB file.

How do I stop the error?

Comment: check this answer on stack https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by creating the missing database and table (with just one field), then dropping both the database and table.