# ERROR - Function 'innodb' already exists

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm looking to start converting some MyISAM tables to INNODB. Running Ubuntu 14.04 Server with MySQL 5.6 ( apt-get upgraded from 5.5 ), 32G ram on 4 core/ 8 thread cpu. Initially had trouble with...

```
could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd after restart of MySQL
```

and

```
Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
```

I followed Rolando's posted advice and the DB isn't crashing or creating a huge error.log anymore.
*( the above issues are gone, just describing leading events )*

**Now I'm concerned about** the following errors before I convert anything to INNODB. Federated can be ignored from what I read, **the second line below** ( also the subject of this post ) concerns me

```
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2014-05-19 01:50:57 30950 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
```

added the following to my.cnf from Rolando's posted advice

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_read_io_threads=12
innodb_write_io_threads=12
innodb_io_capacity=300
innodb_log_file_size=128M
```

Wasn't sure if there should be anything else INNODB related. Based on what I could find also added

```
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
```

That didn't help. Not that I expected it to eliminate an "existing function"...lol

Comment: Did you run mysql_upgrade?

Comment: **@dwjv** unsure so I ran it and it said "This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.6.17". Same issue of "[ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists" in the error.log

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The plugins throwing errors in the error.log were not specifically specified in my.cnf. So I ran...

```
select * from mysql.plugin
```

for MySQL 5.6.17 I deleted the following rows in mysql.plugin

```
innodb ha_innodb.so
federated ha_federated.so
blackhole ha_blackhole.so
archive ha_archive.so
```

Do not delete anything you are not sure about. The above worked for me as...

- I do not use Federated ( accesses data in tables of remote databases )
- INNODB is built into 5.6, no plugin required
- I do not use Blackhole ( accepts data but throws it away and does not store it )
- I do not use Archive ( storing large amounts of data without indexes in a very small footprint )

Comment: you should receive extra credit for listing which plugin does what, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## PROBLEM

`mysql.innodb_table_stats` is part of the MySQL 5.6 install. mysql_upgrade does not generate them. Why ?

- When you install MySQL 5.6 from scratch, that file is generated.
- The file `innodb_table_stats.ibd` does not exists in the mysql schema in MySQL 5.5
- MySQL 5.5's mysql_upgrade is not aware of any innodb system tables.
- In fact, there are five(5) `.ibd` files in MySQL 5.6 in the mysql schema.

## SOLUTION

Please look at these posts I wrote last year on how to make them

- `Dec 07, 2013` : [InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found after upgrade to mysql 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys/54624#54624)
- `Aug 15, 2013` : [Cannot open table mysql/innodb_index_stats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/cannot-open-table-mysql-innodb-index-stats/48189#48189)

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks, I did solve that previously with your posted advice. My concern here is "[ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists" in the error.log

Answer (score 0):

I got these kind of similar errors in PCLinuxOs. What I have done is just renamed the file `/etc/my.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnf.bak` and I was able to start the mysql server. I don't know the exact reason but it worked for me. The settings in that file may be conflicting.