# InnoDB: Error: Table “mysql”.“innodb_table_stats” not found

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mariadb, galera

I've got the same error, although I'm running galera cluster with 3 nodes.
I tried following the instructions from [InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found after upgrade to mysql 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608) but when I get to the step of running the create statements, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1813. Tablespace for table '`mysql`.`innodb_index_stats`' exists.
Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

This made no sense to me, and when I tried to use

```
drop tablespace `innodb_index_stats`;
```

I got an SQL sysntax error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is actually very simple. Here is what happened

When you installed MySQL, the 5 InnoDB systems tables exist in two places

- inside `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` as 5 `.frm` and 5 `.ibd` files
- inside the data dictionary within `ibdata1` (InnoDB System Tablespace)

At some point in your installation, you must have deleted `ibdata1`. This left [the 10 InnoDB system table files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/cannot-open-table-mysql-innodb-index-stats/48189#48189) inside `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` with no data dictionary entry.

**SOLUTION**

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/mysql
rm -f innodb_index_stats.frm
rm -f innodb_index_stats.ibd
rm -f innodb_table_stats.frm
rm -f innodb_table_stats.ibd
rm -f slave_master_info.frm
rm -f slave_master_info.ibd
rm -f slave_relay_log_info.frm
rm -f slave_relay_log_info.ibd
rm -f slave_worker_info.frm
rm -f slave_worker_info.ibd
```

Then, login to MySQL and run the steps from my post : [InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found after upgrade to mysql 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys/54624#54624)

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: Being that this was on a cluster, there was one small change to make in the procedure.  I had to do the delete on all the servers first, then run the create statements from the provided link.  Thank you for the help!