# How DISCARD the tablespace on mariadb while table is not found?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I run the `mysql_upgrade` against my `mariadb 10.3` and get the following error - see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257699/innodb-error-table-mysql-mysql-transaction-registry-not-found-after-upgrad) for details.

```
ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line 85: Tablespace for table 'mysql.transaction_registry' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT
```

When doing the `DISCARD` it does not work as the table does not exist

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show tables;

+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| column_stats              |
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| gtid_slave_pos            |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| index_stats               |
| innodb_index_stats        |
| innodb_table_stats        |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| roles_mapping             |
| servers                   |
| slave_master_info         |
| slave_relay_log_info      |
| slave_worker_info         |
| slow_log                  |
| table_stats               |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
```

```
MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE transaction_registry DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist
```

How to proceed in such a case?

Answer (score -1):

After carefully checking again, I've found `transaction_registry.ibd` on the file system. So I manually deleted the file after stopping `mariadb`. Here you can see what I did:

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql/transaction_registry.ibd
sudo systemctl startb mariadb
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root --force -pxxxxx
...
```

Comment: You can't simply `rm` a `.ibd` file -- there is info in ibdata1 that knows about it.

Comment: I assume it's generally a bad idea to just delete tables but I'm coming from a bad state: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/257699/169281

Comment: Interestingly I've referenced some other posts which also recommend to delete tables files incl. `idb`.  What are then the better options if it's not the correct way? In my case it's not dramatic I don't have production data from a client is only personal stuff